# How to troubleshoot SQLServerAgent startup

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2017

I wonder what can cause SQLServerAgent to stay in "starting" stage after restart.  The service restarted successfully, but I can't get details of any job, or start/stop/delete with msdb procedures. It gives the same error

> Msg 14258, Level 16, State 1, Procedure msdb.dbo.sp_is_sqlagent_starting, Line 9 [Batch Start Line 200]
> Cannot perform this operation while SQLServerAgent is starting. Try again later.

I tried different ways of restarting the server , with SQLServer Management studio, SQLServer Configuration Manager, even manually with NET STOP/NET START.
"SQLServerAgent service successfully started." No errors in Agent log file.
I'm using SQLServer 2017

Thanks

**Update**

With all messages enabled , Agent log has suspicious line

> [393] Waiting for SQL Server to recover database 'msdb'...

No errors though, but maybe I didn't wait long enough -  I stopped the agent after an hour.   Just in case , I verified msdb state in  **[sys].[databases]**, state is 0, state description **ONLINE** .

While agent was in this "starting mode", I kept monitoring queries, and found the one that kept running again and again on msdb database(posting just the very beginning, it seems to be a system function)

```
CREATE FUNCTION sys.fn_sqlagent_jobsteps(@job_id UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NULL,      @step_id INT NULL  ) 
RETURNS @agent_jobsteps TABLE 
 (job_id                  UNIQUEIDENTIFIER    NOT NULL,          
  step_id                 INT                 NOT NULL,             .....
```

After I killed the session with `kill`, the agent finally started and picked up scheduled jobs. That's definitely not a solution, just a temporary hack that allowed me to keep the system up and running.

I already removed all non-necessary jobs ( some articles suggested that too many scheduled jobs might cause agent to hang) .

Agent is running under virtual account ***NT Service\SQLSERVERAGENT***

Comment: Some internet searches turned up some possibilities. Have you reviewed the Fiber Mode settings for SQL Server. Did you change the account that is running SQL Server Agent?

Comment: Account wasn't changed as far as I'm aware.   I'll double check Fiber mode settings , I believe I went through it already , but definitely check it again.

Comment: SQL Agent has its own log, separate to SQL Server's log. Can you get to it?

Comment: @MichaelGreen :  Yeah, I checked Agent log as well. I should have posted it in the very question from the beginning.  Updated.

Comment: @a1ex07, did you try to start SQL Agent in a console verbose mode? in CMD: <Path to your SQL Agent exe>\SQLAGENT.EXE" -i instance anme if used -c -v  If you do not use named instance you can skip -i. You can also copy a command line from service and add -c -v

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ran query to discover what is growing tempdb, found a spid running from SQLAgent - Generic Refresher and calling `EXECUTE msdb.dbo.sp_sqlagent_refresh_job`. Once I killed this spid Sql Agent Service came online properly and I am now able to run, view, drop jobs successfully. I dropped all jobs in case this happens again, not certain of root cause, perhaps a bad schedule or job step.